# Textstring value post to input field in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress 3.8 for my site. I want some ideas for what I am trying to achieve.
Will try to explain in some simple steps:

1. I have a domain search already installed in my site which will tell if a given domain is available or not.
2. If available, the result data (domain) will echo on the page.
3. Bellow the domain result a NEXT submit button is also appearing.

Now! This is where I want your ideas for a solution:

What I want to happen now is when clicking on the input button, then the domain value will get posted to a specific field in another page. I already got the id of that field.

Let me here your good ideas?

Comment: So when you click on the button, some url is called? correct?

Comment: You can either use session or post the data in url

Comment: @user3164114: did my answer below fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your next button, calls another url, then you can assign a hash value to the url.

```
<a href="//nextpage/#domainname.com">NEXT</a>
```

Then with javascript on the next page you can grab the hash value from the url and assign it to the input box.

```
var domainName = window.location.hash.substr(1);
$('input').val(domainName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried it out, but seems to not work. I have already checked for script errors. No errors or conflicts.

I did like this:

```
echo '<a href="http://mydomain.com/#'.$domain.'">NEXT</a>';
```

And then I wrote the following script just before the `</head>` tag and also tried to put it in the footer before the `</body>` tag and in the actual page:

```
<script>
var $domain = window.location.hash.substr(1);
jQuery('form_field_id').val($domain);
</script>
```

As you see above I needed to change the `$` with the `jQuery` for resolving the error I got.

As a result, it seems to not work as the actual 'form_field_id' continues empty in the text field it self.

Any ideas how to get around this?